# Column does not belong to table but it does

Tags: c#, mysql, listview

This is the code and the DueDate and ID column does not belong to table but it is present. The other column is fine, just that two column got the error. Please, help me.

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql2, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();

    lvborrowed.Clear();
    for (int row = 0; row < dt.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(dt.Rows[row]["FirstName"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[row]["LastName"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[row]["BookName"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[row]["Category"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[row]["DateBorrowed"].ToString());

        lvi.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[row]["DueDate"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[row]["Time"].ToString());
        lvi.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[row]["ID"].ToString());

        lvborrowed.Items.Add(lvi);


    }

    lvborrowed.FullRowSelect = true;
    lvborrowed.GridLines = true;
    lvborrowed.View = View.Details;

    lvborrowed.Columns.Add("First Name", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvborrowed.Columns.Add("Last Name", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvborrowed.Columns.Add("Name of Book", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvborrowed.Columns.Add("Category", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    lvborrowed.Columns.Add("Borrow Date", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    lvborrowed.Columns.Add("Date to be Returned", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    lvborrowed.Columns.Add("Borrow Time", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvborrowed.Columns.Add("ID", 0, HorizontalAlignment.Left);


}
catch (Exception en)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error Showlv"+en);
}
```

Comment: "but it is present" in the Database or in `DataTable dt`?

Comment: Please show us: 1) The exact query (sql2) executed 2) The exact schema of the table you are querying

Comment: @sab669 in the database

Comment: @Steve      

                        string sql = "Insert into tbl_borrowed (FirstName,LastName,BookName,Category,DateBorrowed,Time,DueDate,ID) values (@fname,@lname,@bname,@category,@dborrow,@time,@dreturn,@id)";

Comment: If this is an insert query why do you expect the dataadapter to fill a datatable?

Comment: @Steve, i dont know either, im just new to c#. Please help me.

Comment: As Steve said, if you're executing an insert statement your `DataTable` object shouldn't have *any* of those columns. Set a breakpoint on `conn.Close();` and examine your `dt` variable. I think what expect it to have and what it actually has are two very different things. We can't help you when you haven't stated what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want to insert a new record in the tbl_borrowed you don't use a MySqlDataAdapter (albeit it works as well) but you use a MySqlCommand, prepare all the parameters (the @fname, etc....) with the values that you want to insert and finally call the ExecuteNonQuery method of the MySqlCommand. After that you use the MySqlDataAdapter to fill the DataTable but with a _SELECT FirstName,LastName,BookName, .... FROM tbl_borrowed_ statement. I suggest to split your work and do some research on this site how to accomplish these two goals.

Comment: @Steve,i've done that too, but still the same

Comment: Are you telling me that _sql2 = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, DueDate, ID, ... FROM tbl_borrowed_ and then your datatable doesn't contain the DueDate and ID column?

Comment: @Steve, yes....